# greedy algorithm for Maximum directed cut

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, greedy-algorithms

Maximum directed cut: Given a directed graph $G = (V, E)$ with nonnegative edge costs, find a subset $S \subseteq V$ to maximize the total cost of edges out of $S$: $\mathrm{cost}( \{  (u \to v) \mid u \in S \text{ and } v \in \bar{S} \})$.

I am trying to come up with a greedy algorithm for Maximum directed cut with factor 1/4.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We want to help you understand the issues at hand, not do your homework for you.

Comment: considers vertexes  in non-increasing  order with respect to  the
sum of the cost of out edge/out-degree.  when two vertexes have same ratio choose the vertex have lower in-degree.  when a vertex is chosen all the vertexes are connected with it are removed.repeat until all vertexes are chosen or deleted.

Comment: I do not know this algorithm is right.

Comment: Have you tried this algorithm? Does it seem to work? Have you tried proving that it works?

Answer (score 6):

The starting point is the trivial *random* algorithm that chooses $S$ completely at random. Each directed edge is cut with probability $1/4$ (why?), and so in expectation, this random algorithm gives a $1/4$ approximation.

We can derandomize this algorithm using the method of conditional expectations. Arrange the points in order: $1,\ldots,n$. At step $i$, we know which of $1,\ldots,i-1$ are in $S$ and which are in $\bar{S}$. If we put $i \in S$, then we can compute the expected cost of the output given that all further choices are made randomly; and we can do the same if we put $i \in \bar{S}$. One of these choices cuts at least $1/4$ of the edges (in terms of weight), and this is the one we choose.

We can further optimize this algorithm. Consider the following two expressions:
$$
A = \sum_{\substack{j<i\\j\in\bar{S}}} w_{ij} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j>i} w_{ij}, \\
B = \sum_{\substack{j<i\\j\in S}} w_{ji} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j>i} w_{ji}.
$$
(Here $w_{ij}$ is the cost of the edge from $i$ to $j$.)
If $A>B$ then the derandomized algorithm puts $i$ in $S$, whereas if $A<B$ it puts $i$ in $\bar{S}$ (if $A=B$ it doesn't matter). We can perhaps think of this algorithm as a greedy algorithm.

---

As an aside, the so-called *double greedy* algorithm gives a $1/2$ approximation algorithm. The greedy algorithm you suggest in the comments is good in combination with the random algorithm: if you run both and choose the better solution, you get a $2/5$ approximation (see [Feige's paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.0406.pdf)). The semidefinite relaxation gives the (probably) optimal approximation ratio, which is roughly 0.874.